How do I perform error-handling on non-existent web image that throws a HTTP 404 error?
I am trying to create a gt table with cropped headshots of baseball players, however there is no image available for one player (Cameron Sisneros) and this causes an HTTP error 404. Ideally, absence of a player image would default to a cropped version of the logo for Minor League Baseball (included in code below). If I omit this one player, the code runs fine, see image below. However, I'd like a more scalable solution to handle this type of error and display all players, with a fallback image for those that don't have an available headshot.
library(cropcircles)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
 
df_test <- structure(list(player = c("Matt Shaw", "Owen Caissie", 
                                     "Cameron Sisneros"), 
          matchup_batter_id = c(807713L, 683357L, 815133L), 
          HR = c(4L, 4L, 3L)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) %>%  
   
 # filter(player != 'Cameron Sisneros') %>% 
  mutate(headshot = paste0("https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-photos/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto/w_360/v1/people/",matchup_batter_id,"/headshot/milb/current")) %>% 
  mutate(headshot = cropcircles::circle_crop(headshot,
                                border_size = 12,
                                border_colour = "black")
          ) # Ideally an HTTP error 404 would default to cropped image of the league logo
  # League logo found here: https://images.ctfassets.net/iiozhi00a8lc/7eeTdW5zGYe0sW2ZlIle7E/990464d4b5e4e3b3a65cb6c56ce808ea/milb-alt.svg

# Construct gt table
df_test %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  gt_img_rows(headshot, height = 37, img_source = "local") #add cropped headshots 



Have you tried ifelse()?

@ahorn no i haven't.  What would be the proper first argument of an ifelse statement that would connote "if an HTTP error is encountered"?  Worth mentioning that I have attempted to use the try wrapped around the mutate function, but no luck there.

I would have to install the cropcircles package, try to request a non-existent page, and see how the return value is structured. You can try assign that to an object, and use str() to see how to specify whether it is an error or not.

You could use purrr::possibly() adverb to create a modified version of cropcircles::circle_crop() that returns some default value instead of an error.
To avoid replacing all values with the default when there's even a single bad URL in the input column, you'd need to process one URL at a time, so for example purrr:map_chr() in a mutate() call or just use rowwise() grouping:
library(cropcircles)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)

# default image
default_headshot <- 
  cropcircles::circle_crop("https://images.ctfassets.net/iiozhi00a8lc/7eeTdW5zGYe0sW2ZlIle7E/990464d4b5e4e3b3a65cb6c56ce808ea/milb-alt.svg",
                           border_size = 12, border_colour = "black")

# return default_headshot in case of an error,
cc_possibly <- possibly(cropcircles::circle_crop, otherwise = default_headshot)


df_test <- structure(list(player = c("Matt Shaw", "Owen Caissie", 
                                     "Cameron Sisneros"), 
                          matchup_batter_id = c(807713L, 683357L, 815133L), 
                          HR = c(4L, 4L, 3L)), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) %>%  
  mutate(headshot = paste0("https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-photos/image/upload/c_fill,g_auto/w_360/v1/people/",matchup_batter_id,"/headshot/milb/current")) %>% 
  # process URLs one by one
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(headshot = cc_possibly(headshot, border_size = 12, border_colour = "black")) %>%
  # drop rowwise grouping
  ungroup() 

# Construct gt table
df_test %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  gt_img_rows(headshot, height = 37, img_source = "local") %>%
  # for reprex output
  gt_reprex_image()


Created on 2024-09-29 with reprex v2.1.1

Amazing! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!
